# Text not horizontally aligned with \item

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate, flalign

A bit nickpicky, but `\item` from `enumerate` and `flalign*` don't line up correctly, such that there is a small vertical distance between the two.

Code surrounding error:

```
\begin{enumerate}

%some long text

\item

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
$x * y = \dfrac{xy}{x+y+1}$

$y * x = \dfrac{yx}{y+x+1} = \dfrac{xy}{x+y+1}$

Since $x * y = y * x$, $*$ is communicative.

\item 
\begin{flalign*}
x*(y*z) &= x* \left(\frac{yz}{y+z+1} \right) &\\
&= \dfrac{x \cdot \frac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x + \frac{yz}{y+z+1} + 1} &\\
&= \dfrac{xyz}{(x+1)(y+z+1) + yz} &\\
&= \dfrac{xyz}{xy+xz+yz + x+y+z + 1} &
\end{flalign*}

%more long text

\end{enumerate}

%even more text

\end{enumerate}
```

[image: Output (red circle at spacing issue)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by turning your code into a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flalign` is a display enviornment that takes the full width of the page and offsets the display with vertical space so the fact that the `ii` appears to the left of it is more or less accidental and there is no possibility of it aligning with the first line of text.

To use display math in an enumeration use

```
\item $\begin{aligned}[t].....
```

`\begin{aligned}[t]` is designed to do exactly what you want, produce an alignment with its reference point on the first line so other text will align with the first line of the display.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was exactly what I was looking for! For future use, what does the `[t]` do in the `aligned` environment, and are there other optional parameters you could input?

Comment: `[t]` for top (which is what you asked for, try `[b]` to see the difference (or `c`) @EnverAman